# Is it possible to use HTML designer in VS 2013 for an MVC Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to view an MVC web application in the HTML designer in Visual Studio 2013?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to create a Web Application, but cannot find the site.master - not even in the Views/Shared folder in solution explorer.

The Web Application is in c# and is MVC.

Where can I view the site.master, so I may change the template to my liking?

Comment: Check "Layouts" http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for. I basically want to use the HTML designer for an MVC Web Application - or know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible currently it will be very difficult for an HTML designer to even know what is meant by Razor code in most cases but there is some sort of solution to this by using Page Inspector already available since VS2012

All you need to do is right click on the View and choose "View in Page Inspector"

[image]

**Update**

Layout screenshot

[image]

Comment: Oh ok.  So if I wanted to change the default look of the page, without having to click on each individual View is that possible?  For example, in a web form web application you can just edit the site.master to change the appearance of the overall site. Is there any way at all possible to do this, for example in your picture placing a logo in the "your logo here" area, so that you don't have to place a logo on every single View? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes you can do that under the Shared folder.  There is a _ViewStart.cshtml and you can declare your Layout there.  See updated screenshot

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!  So would you recommend using MVC or Web Forms then, for this very reason that we cannot use the HTML designer in MVC?  I know there are tons of discussions on MVC vs Web Form, but still nothing straight to the point for building websites in my opinion.

Comment: For me since I used MVC I never looked back, learning curve might be steep but once you get hooked it is very easy and you deploy in a much faster way.  Combine it with opensource or free frameworks (like s#arp, open access ORM, EF), it will rock.  I just cant live now without view models.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really do appreciate it.  I'm converting from VS 2008 to VS 2013 and also converting from VB to c# AND from Web Forms to MVC, so I am overwhelmed, especially when all I wanted to do was change the design / look of a web application and it has taken me 2 hours to figure out why the HTML Designer and Site.Master page were no where to be found :s  --> I HOPE ALL THESE ATTEMPTED CONVERSIONS IN CODING IS A GOOD IDEA IN THE LONG RUN